# UWP - How to annotate image (xaml/c#)

Tags: win-universal-app, universal

I have requirement to allow annotations on image. Once user draws the annotations, I need to save the image with annotations. Also I need to give an option to retrieve and update the existing annotations.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any blog or any suggestions on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such build-in control exist, you have to implement your own. But I think its quite easy to create one.

Basically you may let your customer create a input Control(a user control is preferred) and type annotations, then save the control position also the Text by your code somewhere in your app.

When user wants to output the image, use RenderTargetBitmap to create the final result.

When user wants to modify the text, simply let them edit on the user control.